# Boundary condition of hard wall potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering, boundary-conditions

I have a potential that is like
$$
V(x)=  \left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x >0 \\
\infty & x \leq 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Using the boundary condition at $\psi(x=0)=0$ I have found that the wave function looks like
$$\psi(x)=a\sin kx$$
But I don't see any other boundary condition to find the constant $a$. Is there any other boundary conditions here that I am missing?

Comment: Your wavefunction is a probability amplitude. Probability has to be normalised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amplitude of the wave function normally comes from normalisation i.e. we require:

$$\int \psi^*\psi~dx = 1 $$

The problem is that here the wave function is a semi-infinite plane wave and cannot be normalised. In real life this isn't a problem as there are no infinite (or semi-infinite) plane waves and a finite plane wave can be normalised. The (semi) infinite plane wave is a mathematical ideal that we use for convenience.

So the tl;dr is that you cannot determine the constant $a$. Just set it to unity and shrug!

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!